# MySql hierarchical query, how to get sequence from 1 to n

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get in MySQL query the same result as Oracle's

```
 WITH t(n) AS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM t;
 or
select level
from dual
connect by level < 100
```

?

Here is my thoughts about this in MySQL SQL

```
select *
from
  (select @level := ifnull(@level,1) +1  as prev
  )a
where a.prev < 100;
```

but sub-query don't executes dynamically

Comment: do you have any mysql sql already?

Comment: @otopolsky Yes, I do

Comment: @otopolsky updated post

Comment: Can you give some example data and what you want to get back?